# HTML parsing JSoup img doesn't work

Tags: java, android, html

### NEW LOGCAT

```
06-21 13:24:25.850: W/ActivityThread(25137): Application it.rs.esempioparsinglistview is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-21 13:24:40.704: W/System.err(25137): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /portals/v3_2/images/background-images.jpg
06-21 13:24:40.714: W/System.err(25137):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
06-21 13:24:40.714: W/System.err(25137):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
06-21 13:24:40.724: W/System.err(25137):    at it.rs.esempioparsinglistview.MainActivity$ParsingPaginaWeb.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:119)
06-21 13:24:40.724: W/System.err(25137):    at it.rs.esempioparsinglistview.MainActivity$ParsingPaginaWeb.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-21 13:24:40.724: W/System.err(25137):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-21 13:24:40.724: W/System.err(25137):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-21 13:24:40.734: W/System.err(25137):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-21 13:24:40.744: W/System.err(25137):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-21 13:24:40.744: W/System.err(25137):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-21 13:24:40.744: W/System.err(25137):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-21 13:29:03.541: W/ActivityThread(25327): Application it.rs.esempioparsinglistview is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-21 13:29:16.984: W/System.err(25327): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /portals/v3_2/images/background-images.jpg
06-21 13:29:17.004: W/System.err(25327):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
06-21 13:29:17.004: W/System.err(25327):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
06-21 13:29:17.014: W/System.err(25327):    at it.rs.esempioparsinglistview.MainActivity$ParsingPaginaWeb.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:118)
06-21 13:29:17.014: W/System.err(25327):    at it.rs.esempioparsinglistview.MainActivity$ParsingPaginaWeb.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-21 13:29:17.014: W/System.err(25327):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-21 13:29:17.014: W/System.err(25327):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-21 13:29:17.024: W/System.err(25327):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-21 13:29:17.024: W/System.err(25327):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-21 13:29:17.034: W/System.err(25327):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-21 13:29:17.034: W/System.err(25327):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

### HTML code

[image]

```
  <figure class="f-art-list">
    <a href="/news/Cronaca/295507/news.aspx" id="MainContent_ListNews_rptNews_lnkToNews1_0" title="Ai domiciliari dopo atti incendiari nei confronti di imprenditore di Noci. Arrestati due santermani">
<img style="display: block;" data-original="http://cdn.livenetwork.it/news/295507/634903800413300428_arresto_carabinieri_HomeStandard_191x95.jpg" src="http://cdn.livenetwork.it/news/295507/634903800413300428_arresto_carabinieri_HomeStandard_191x95.jpg" class="lazy img-responsive" alt="Ai domiciliari dopo atti incendiari nei confronti di imprenditore di Noci. Arrestati due santermani" title="Ai domiciliari dopo atti incendiari nei confronti di imprenditore di Noci. Arrestati due santermani">
        </a>
</figure>
```

Hi i have problem on parsing HTML JSoup, LogCat evidence problem on this part:

```
cache.immagineart.setImageBitmap(immaginiart.get(pos));
```

### LogCat error messages

```
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941): Process: it.rs.esempioparsinglistview, PID: 15941
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at it.rs.esempioparsinglistview.ParsingArrayAdapter.getView(ParsingArrayAdapter.java:78)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2295)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1231)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2553)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5142)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-20 12:30:17.097: E/AndroidRuntime(15941):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


ParsingArrayAdapter.java:78 is this: cache.immagineart.setImageBitmap(immaginiart.get(pos));
```

This Part is for insert `Bitmap` in `ArrayList` for img 
The URL parsing is: http://www.santeramolive.it/news/tutte-le-news.aspx

### Mainactivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lista = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.main_lista);//list id

    //asynctask
    ParsingPaginaWeb parsing = new ParsingPaginaWeb();
    parsing.execute("");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class ParsingPaginaWeb extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    ArrayList<String> titoli; //list title
    ArrayList<String> descrizioni; //list description
    ArrayList<String> date; // list date
    ArrayList<String> categorie; // list category
    ArrayList<Bitmap> immaginiart; // lista img

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
        descrizioni = new ArrayList<String>();
        date= new ArrayList<String>();
        categorie= new ArrayList<String>();
        immaginiart = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.santeramolive.it/news/tutte-le-news.aspx")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
                    .timeout(30000).get();

            Element listarticoli = doc.getElementsByClass("list-articles").first();


            Elements articoli = listarticoli.getElementsByClass("art-list");
            for(Element articolo : articoli)
            {

                    // title
                    String titolo = articolo.getElementsByClass("t-art-list").first().text();

                    // description


                    String descrizione = articolo.getElementsByTag("p").first().text();

                    // insert in arraylist
                    titoli.add(titolo);
                    descrizioni.add(descrizione);

                    Elements dcs = articolo.getElementsByClass("date-tag-art-list");
                    for(Element dc : dcs)
                    {

                    String data = dc.getElementsByClass("date-art-list").first().text();

                    String categoria = dc.getElementsByClass("tag-art-list").first().text();
                    date.add(data); // add date
                    categorie.add(categoria);// add category
                    }
                    //img part
                    Elements imgdivs = articolo.getElementsByClass("f-art-list");
                    for(Element imgsdiv : imgdivs)
                    {

                    Element divimg = imgsdiv.getElementsByClass("lazy img-responsive").first();
                    String imgSrc = divimg.attr("src");
                    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    immaginiart.add(bitmap);

                    }

             }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {


        ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli, descrizioni, date, categorie, immaginiart);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

}
```

### ParsingArrayAdapter.java

```
public class ParsingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

//riferimenti statici alle risorse e agli id
private final static int LAYOUT = R.layout.riga_listview;
private final static int TITOLO = R.id.riga_listview_titolo;
private final static int DESCRIZIONE = R.id.riga_listview_descrizione;
private final static int DATA = R.id.riga_listview_data;
private final static int CATEGORIA = R.id.riga_listview_categoria;
private final static int IMMAGINE= R.id.riga_listview_immagine;

ArrayList<String> titoli;
ArrayList<String> descrizioni; 
ArrayList<String> date; 
ArrayList<String> categorie;
ArrayList<Bitmap> immaginiart;

Context c; //context
LayoutInflater inflater; //layout inflater

public ParsingArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titoli,ArrayList<String> descrizioni, ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> categorie, ArrayList<Bitmap> immaginiart)
{
    super(context,TITOLO);
    this.c = context;
    this.titoli = titoli;
    this.descrizioni = descrizioni;
    this.date= date;
    this.categorie= categorie;
    this.immaginiart= immaginiart;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return titoli.size(); 
}


@Override
public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
{
    CacheRiga cache; //cache
    if(view==null)
    {
        // creo la view ma non l'attacco alla lista in quanto devo ancora modificare
        // i testi delle textview
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
        cache = new CacheRiga(); 
        cache.titolo = (TextView) view.findViewById(TITOLO); 
        cache.descrizione = (TextView) view.findViewById(DESCRIZIONE);//collego descrizione
        cache.data = (TextView) view.findViewById(DATA);
        cache.categoria = (TextView) view.findViewById(CATEGORIA);
        cache.immagineart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);
        view.setTag(cache);
    }
    else
    {
        cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); dalla view
    }

    cache.titolo.setText(titoli.get(pos));
    cache.descrizione.setText(descrizioni.get(pos));
    cache.data.setText(date.get(pos)); 
    cache.categoria.setText(categorie.get(pos));
    cache.immagineart.setImageBitmap(immaginiart.get(pos));

    return view;
}

private class CacheRiga { 
    public TextView titolo; 
    public TextView descrizione;
    public TextView data; 
    public TextView categoria; 
    public ImageView immagineart; 
}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Post the logcat please.

Comment: and this part is correc ? for parsimg imags ? Element divimg = imgsdiv.getElementsByClass("lazy img-responsive").first();
                    String imgSrc = divimg.attr("src");
                    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

Comment: Please post more logcat lines and post them in one block. (now it is a mess as you self can see). It is strange that `cache.immagineart.setImageBitmap(immaginiart.get(pos));` causes a parse error as at that moment nothing is parsed. Only a Bitmap is pulled from an ArrayList. Please make two statements out it it: `BitMap bitmap=immaginiart.get(pos); cache.immagineart.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` And then see which statement causes the error. Malformed Bitmap? Save such a bitmap to file and view with extern app. DOn't know if your decoding is correct. Please post code in a normal block. Not here.

Comment: `ERRORE NEL PARSING` is your own log statement. Please say such things! So you have an exeption there and it could well be in decodeStream. You are not printing the exception message so you throw away valuable info. Change statement to ` Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING: " + e.getMessage());`; add an e.printStackTrace() there too.

Comment: How many items can you get in in your lists? Is the exception already on the first item of `for(Element articolo : articoli)`?

Comment: get 10 items in my list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
 String imgSrc = divimg.attr("src");
```

because divimg== null. The stacktrace is clearly showing this. Further the app crashes. Why didn't you tell? Why didn't you post more of the logcat/stacktrace? You would have been helped sooner.

Change your code to:

```
                Element divimg = imgsdiv.getElementsByClass("lazy img-responsive").first();

                if ( divimg==null)
                    {
                    Log.e(TAG, "divimg==null: " + titolo);

                    immaginiart.add(null);                      
                    }
                else
                {
                String imgSrc = divimg.attr("src");
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                immaginiart.add(bitmap);
                }
```

This will not decode the image but just display an empty image.

Comment: i have change code, but how  can i  do for display image article?

Comment: Show the piece of the html source that you want to parse. Nicely formatted. Not in a comment.

Comment: Please copy and paste as text here.

Comment: But not formatted. The first step would be to get the img tag by `.getElementByTag("img");` Please try.